# How can depth of flow in a supercritical flow get affected when the flow passes through a constriction of width less than the critical width?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering, open-channel-flow

When a supercritical flow approaches a constriction having a width less than the critical width does the depth of supercritical flow decrease upstream so as to increase specific energy? If it does then how come is it said that supercritical flow has an u/s control and is not effected by d/s conditions?